# Problems with SaveAsync task in DynamoDB for C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, task, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to save my administrator class object to DynamoDB using Context.SaveAsync method:

```
// Save admin to DynamoDB.
context.SaveAsync(admin,(result)=>{
  if (result.Exception == null)
  { 
    Console.WriteLine("admin saved");
  }
});
```

but it keeps bothering me with following error:

```
cannot convert `lambda expression' to non-delegate type `system.threading.cancellationtoken'
```

How do I handle this issue ?. I'm using Xamarin Studio for OS X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`DynamoDBContext.SaveAsync`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/MDynamoDBv2_DataModel_DynamoDBContext_SaveAsync_T_CancellationToken.html) takes a type `T`, and a `CancellationToken`. It does not take any form of delegate type, at all.

What you want is to do is:

```
public async Task SaveAsync<T>(T entity, CancellationToken ct)
{
     await context.SaveAsync<T>(entity, ct);
     Console.WriteLine("entity saved");
}
```